# Programmatically create SMTP credentials when using AWS SES SMTP interface via Nodemailer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, nodemailer, amazon-ses

I have a Lambda function inside of a VPC and a VPC endpoint set up to access AWS SES from within that Lambda function. Also, I manage my infrastructure via Cloudformation.

Then, from within the above-mentioned Lambda (using Node.js 16) I am able to successfully execute the following snippet with Nodemailer in order to send an email via the SMTP interface of AWS SES:

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: sourceEmailAddress,
  to: 'myemail@something.com',
  text: 'This is some text',
  html: '<b>This is some HTML</b>',
  subject: 'Nodemailer SMTP transporter',
};

const region = process.env.AWS_REGION;
const smtpTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  port: 587,
  host: `email-smtp.${region}.amazonaws.com`,
  auth: {
    user: '...',
    pass: '...',
  }
});

await smtpTransporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
```

As you can see in the snippet above, I have to hard-code a username and password, which is not nice. Is there a nicer way of doing this, like creating the user via Cloudformation and then pass it down to the Lambda function to use it?

Also, I prefer a "programmatic" way of creating the SMTP credentials, instead of the manual way described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/smtp-credentials.html